# How to navigate to Particular location Based On Latitude Longitude

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am Developing sample react-native Application, in that application i am using react-native-maps. It's Working fine maps showing current Location, But ,I have Custom latitude Longitude,now I want to navigate to that particular location when i click a Button.

Here This is My Code:

```
 <MapView
                     ref='map'
              style={styles.map}
              region={this.state.mapRegion}
              showsUserLocation={true}
              followUserLocation={true}
              zoomEnabled={true}
              pitchEnabled={true}
              showsCompass={true}
              showsBuildings={true}
              showsTraffic={true}
              showsIndoors={true}
              onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange.bind(this)}
              onPress={this.onMapPress.bind(this)}>
             {this.state.markers.length != 0 || this.state.markers != undefined ?(
              this.state.markers.map(marker => (
               <MapView.Marker
                 coordinate={{
                   latitude: marker.Latitude||this.state.lastLat||region.latitude,
                   longitude:marker.Longitude||this.state.lastLong||region.longitude
                 }}
                 image = {
                  marker.EmergencyService == true ?(
                    require('./Imgs/emergencyService.png')):
                    (require('./Imgs/regularService.png'))
                 }
                 onCalloutPress={() => this.bookDoctorsAppointment(marker)}
         >
         <MyCustomMarkerView marker={marker}  navigator={this.props.navigator}/>
         </MapView.Marker>
              )      
         )):(<View></View>)}
            </MapView>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are a bunch of methods available, I try `animateToRegion` below:

https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md#methods

So try using that ref:

```
class MyComp extends Component {
    setMap = () => {
        if (this.map) {
            console.log('keys on this.map:', Object.keys(this.map));
            this.map.animateToRegion(...);
        }
    }
    getRefMap = el => this.map = el; // this also triggers when <MapView unmounts but el will be `null` so you can test if (el) { alert('mounted') } else { alert('unmounted') }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text onPress={this.setMap}>Set map!</Text>
                <MapView ref={this.getRefMap} ...>;
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't get Can you explain this

Comment: Forgive me please, I am not so good at English, I can write it, but my comprehension and ability to express is bad. @Lavaraju attach a `ref` to your component and then you can see the methods on the ref instance.